# Fetch Only Last Entry by user daily

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a small reporting application. I have two tables

**Agent Table Data**

```
AgentID  AgentName
-------  ---------
1001     ABC
1002     XYZ
1003     POI
1004     JKL
```

**Report Table Data**

```
ReportID  AgentId  Labor  Mandays  Amount  SubmitDate
--------  -------  -----  -------  ------  ----------
1         1001     30     10       5000    11/12/2011
2         1001     44     18       8000    11/14/2011
3         1002     33     75       3022    11/12/2011
4         1001     10     10       1500    11/14/2011
5         1002     10     10       1800    11/14/2011
6         1001     10     10       1400    11/14/2011
7         1003     40     40       1500    11/14/2011
8         1003     40     40       1800    11/14/2011
```

I want to generate a report which gives us output like

```
ReportID  AgentId  Labor  Mandays  Amount  SubmitDate
--------  -------  -----  -------  ------  ----------
1         1001     30     10       5000    11/12/2011
3         1002     33     75       3022    11/12/2011
6         1001     10     10       1400    11/14/2011
5         1002     10     10       1800    11/14/2011
8         1003     40     40       1800    11/14/2011
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention what **VERSION** of SQL Server you're using - if you're on 2005 or newer, you can use a CTE (Common Table Expression) with the `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
;WITH LastPerAgent AS
(
   SELECT 
       AgentID, ReportID, Labor, Mandays, Amount, SubmitDate,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AgentID,SubmitDate
                         ORDER BY ReportID DESC) AS 'RowNum'
   FROM dbo.Report
)
SELECT 
   AgentID, ReportID, Labor, Mandays, Amount, SubmitDate,
FROM LastPerAgent
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

This CTE "partitions" your data by `AgentID` and `SubmitDate`, and for each partition, the `ROW_NUMBER` function hands out sequential numbers, starting at 1 and ordered by `ReportID DESC` - so the "last" row (with the highest `ReportID`) for each `(AgentID, SubmitDate)` pair gets `RowNum = 1` which is what I select from the CTE in the SELECT statement after it.

PS: this doesn't work 100% on your input data, since you've not defined how to group and how to eliminate rows.... you might need to adapt this query a bit, based on your requirements...

Comment: I am not getting the result I need as its only returning 1 row per Agent, I am looking for 1 Agent and its daily last reporting values.